# Why does my Python CLI project structure result in ModuleNotFoundErrors?

Tags: python

I have a Python application used as a CLI, let's call it `foo`. My problem is that the project works if I do `pip install .` in the root of my repository, and then execute `foo` in the terminal.
But if I try to run the source code directly with the Python interpreter, then the `import`s don't work.

(I'm new to Python, and this is the first project I'm maintaining, so I suspect that I'm doing something incorrectly or not in an idiomatic way.)

The repository structure is the following, I have this folder structure.

```
.
├── src/
│   └── foo/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __main__.py
│       └── applogic.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.cfg
```

`__init__.py` is an empty file. `applogic.py` contains various methods, let's say it defines one method:

```
def execute_foo():
    ...
```

And `__main__.py` is the main entry point of the CLI, which imports and uses a method from `applogic.py`:

```
from foo.applogic import execute_foo

def cli():
    execute_foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':  # pragma: no cover
    cli()
```

This setup works if I install the package locally with `pip install .` in the root of the repo, and running it with `foo` in the terminal.
But if I do `python src/foo/__main__.py`, then the import fails with this error.

```
$ python src/foo/__main__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GitHub\foo\src\foo\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from foo.applogic import execute_foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

If I remove the package name in the import statement, so change it from

```
from foo.applogic import execute_foo
```

to

```
from applogic import execute_foo
```

Then it works when executing the code with `python`.
But then it doesn't work when I install the package with `pip install` and try executing it with `foo`. It fails on the import with the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'execute_foo'
```

So my question is: is there a way to structure the project and use imports in a way that it works both when executing the code directly with `python`, and when it is packaged with `pip install`?

(If it helps, here is the source code of the real project: https://github.com/markvincze/sabledocs)

Comment: are you using a virtual environment like venv?

Comment: Move __main__.py out of foo package/directory

Comment: This is a common FAQ. In a Unix-like shell, try `PYTHONPATH=src python -m foo`

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'm not using a venv at the moment, I'll look into that. I don't think moving `__main.py__` out would work, then it wouldn't be part of the package. The solution to the problem was using the `-e` flag with `pip install`, as suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure looks OK. As said in comment, you should use a [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). After activating the venv, you can type `python -m pip install -e .` ([`-e` is for editable](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-e)). It allows you to have all dependencies installed and still work on files.

Then you can do either:
`python -m foo` or `python src/foo/__main__.py`.

Comment: Thanks, using the `-e` flag did the trick, with that I can do code changes without having to reinstall the package every time. I'm not using `venv`s at all at the moment, I'll look into that too, thanks!